# Excluding-9999 data when using graduated symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm using QGIS 3.16. I've some data where secret statistic values are encoded as -9999 in multiple columns. When I go in the layer tab "Symbology", I choose to use "Graduated", then select my column name. Then, I press "Classify". It includes my -9999 values but I want to exclude them. I've already had solutions to do it e.g

- using PyQGIS using methods inherited from https://qgis.org/api/classQgsClassificationMethod.html to classify and push the classification in Rule-based symbology
- filter provider source on my column to exclude -9999, classify, transform Symbology as Rule-based and then remove the filter and add the -9999 value in a new rule

I would prefer a GUI based approach so, solution 1 is not what I want.

The solution #2 needs a lot of intermediate steps each time and need to be repeated too frequently e.g for each column or each classification change.

Do you have any other approach to solve this issue e.g excluding one or more values before using "Graduated" classification?

Ideally, I should be able to exclude it using the GUI but it's not possible in the current QGIS (to my knowledge).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have just to create a QGIS expression for your graduated symbology `nullif("your_field_of_values", -9999)` ([QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#nullif)), `NULL` values are excluded.

To exclude many values, consider a filter like `CASE WHEN ... END` statement ([QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#case)).

Comment: Thanks. Waiting for other inputs if any. If not, will accept your answer

Comment: I'm proud to answer at one of your very rare questions !

Comment: For multiple replacements, I prefer `if("your_field_of_values" IN (-9999, 0), NULL,"your_field_of_values")` Here I use `0` but it could be any value and the list could be longer or I could use a more complex condition e.g something like `if("your_field_of_values" = -9999 OR "your_field_of_values" < 0, NULL,"your_field_of_values")`